# In C#, using "using" results in errors, is there a better practice than just not using "using"?

Tags: c#, using, streamwriter, memorystream, csvhelper

I have the following method:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope", Justification = "If we dispose of the csvWriter, it won't be available to write.")]
    public static MemoryStream CreateCsvStream(IEnumerable<object> records)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new(memoryStream);
        CsvWriter csvWriter = new(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<bool>(new CollendaBooleanConverter());
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<bool?>(new CollendaBooleanConverter());
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateOnly>(new CollendaDateOnlyConverter());
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateOnly?>(new CollendaDateOnlyConverter());
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal>(new CollendaDecimalConverter());
        csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<decimal?>(new CollendaDecimalConverter());
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

This works, but as hinted in the `SuppressMessage`, if I use `using` so `MemoryStream`, `StreamWriter`, and/or `CsvWriter` are disposed of, when I later execute the following code:

```
    private void Upload(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        _sftpClient.Connect();
        _ = memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string filePath = _collendaSftpConfig?.FilePath
            ?.InsertTimestamp()
            ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("CollendaSftpConfig configuration is missing FilePath.");

        // Renci.SshNet's Sftp Client seems to have some async support, but it seems much more complicated to consume.
        // There is no clear benefit to using it at this time.
        _sftpClient.UploadFile(memoryStream, filePath);
        _sftpClient.Disconnect();
    }
```

I'll get an error like:

> System.ObjectDisposedException
> HResult=0x80131622
> Message=Cannot access a closed Stream.
> Source=System.Private.CoreLib
> StackTrace:
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_StreamClosed(String objectName)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin loc)
> at Enpal.Collenda.Client.SftpUploader.CollendaSftpClient.Upload(MemoryStream memoryStream) in C:\projects\FinTech\collenda-finance-listener\Collenda.Client.SftpUploader\CollendaSftpClient.cs:line 59

I did not experiment with every permutation of adding or not adding using to each of these, but I did try adding to all and some of them and received similar results.

Of course, the simple "solution" is just to leave them out and suppress this, but I'm concerned whether this is a reliable solution and whether there may be a better way to handle this situation (and potentially similiar situations in the future).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to read from the stream afterwards, and that's all. In that case, you *don't* want to dispose of the stream (because you still want to be able to read) but probably you *do* want to dispose of the `StreamWriter`. (It won't actually matter with `MemoryStream`, but I can understand wanting to do it.)

The simplest option here is to use the `StreamWriter` constructor that allows you to suppress it closing the underlying stream:

```cs
public static MemoryStream CreateCsvStream(IEnumerable<object> records)
{
    // No using statement here, because we want the stream to stay open
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new();

    // We *do* want to dispose of the StreamWriter
    using StreamWriter streamWriter = new(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true);

    // I assume that CsvWriter implements IDisposable too
    using CsvWriter csvWriter = new(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Write to csvWriter here
    ...

    // No need to flush the StreamWriter - that'll happen when it's disposed
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`StreamWriter` by default closes underlying stream on `Dispose`, you can use constructor accepting [`leaveOpen` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-io-stream-system-text-encoding-system-int32-system-boolean))  and set it to `true`:

> `leaveOpen` Boolean
> `true` to leave the stream open after the `StreamWriter` object is disposed; otherwise, `false`.

```cs
MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
using StreamWriter streamWriter = new(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true);
```

Also when wrapping the `StreamWriter` into `using` there is no more need to call `Flush`  - it will happen automatically on `Dispose`.