# C# MemoryStream and returning a csv file within a controller using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, memorystream, csvhelper

**Intended Outcome**: From an instance of a specific object (Item) to output the data into a csv file within a API controller.
**Approach**: To achieve this I have written a class called Item with two properties. Then assigned two records to them within a List. To create the actual csv the CsvHelper library is being used and the initial file being created from a memory stream. Then the records written to the CSV and attempted to be returned.
**Problem**: Does not work. Error is returned saying "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream." I have researched and attempted to place the enclosing { } tags around to ensure it is not disposed but somehow cannot get this to work. In theory this should be simple but cannot determine where this is incorrect.

Edited Code: I have used leaveopen and this still does not work.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using CsvHelper;



namespace WebAPIExample2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class ExportProducts : ControllerBase
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetProd()
        {
            List<Item> item = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item { Name = "John", Description = "Brown" },
            new Item { Name = "John", Description = "Brown" }
        };

            // Create a memory stream to hold the CSV data.
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, leaveOpen:true))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            { 
                csv.WriteRecords(item);
                writer.Flush();
                memoryStream.Position = 0; // Reset the position to the beginning of the stream.

                // Return the CSV data as a file.
                return File(memoryStream, "text/csv", "exported_items.csv");
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @NineBerry - that is necessary but not sufficient.  It is also necessary to inform the `StreamWriter` that the underlying stream should be left open by passing `true` for `leaveOpen` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629150/3744182) by Jon Skeet to [In C#, using "using" results in errors, is there a better practice than just not using "using"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75629101/3744182).  In fact that question seems to be a perfect duplicate since it is about CsvHelper specifically.

Comment: @dbc, thanks I actually solved it using the link you provided!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Comment: Why rely on a third-party library. Use the .net built-in TextFieldParser class in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO class.   It supports CSV files and will not have the longer term compatibility / lack of support eventually you will run into with third-party libraries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN has a CSV file link halfway down the page.  Link is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files

Comment: @snj - `TextFieldParser` is handy but it's only for reading CSV files.  The question is about writing though, and MSFT doesn't have a built-in equivalent for writing as far as I know.